# can I get iOS 5.0.1 Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, data-storage

I am implementing the do-not-backup attribute for my app for iOS 5.0.1 and above. And as [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) suggests, there is a different way to set the key for iOS 5.1 and above.
I can test it for iOS 5.1 and above (that nothing is crashing) with the simulators available but hoe to test for 5.0.1??

Comment: Open Xcode>Preferences>Downloads>iOS 5.0 Simulator is there. Just install it and you are good to go.

Comment: does iCloud supports/works in simulator.?

Comment: iOS 5.0 does not support do-not-backup, but iOS 5.0.1 does. 5.0 Simulator is of no use for that

Comment: From what I understand when apple does a release for something like `iOS 5.0.1` it is actually covered under `iOS 5.0 Simulator` xcode will just update to handle it. It's the big ones that you need download yourself cause there the ones that add new functionality where as the others are just bug fixes.

Comment: @JohnDude: no it does not update its iOS 5.0 simulator to iOS 5.0.1 simulator. It just gets the new 5.1 Simulator whenevr it is released

Comment: @NikitaP that was just my understanding but I am relatively new to this so I am probably completely wrong. Thanks for update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,I don't think you can get 5.0.1 simulator. The best thing would be testing your app in a iOS 5.0.1 device.